# Conditional split showing error

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

Iam trying to split records into two tables using conditional split based on salary I am getting the following error

> Error at conditional split the data type dt_wstr and dt_i4 are incompatible with for binary operator

Comment: You should share your failing code.

Comment: Error at conditional split the data type dt wstr and  dt14 are incompatible with for binary operator

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a type cast method

```
[COLUMN1] == (DT_WSTR,50)[COLUMN2]
```

The error is thrown because you are comparing a string value to an integer value. Casting the integer value to string will solve the issue.

```
DT_WSTR : Unicode string
DT_I4 : Integer
```